# How can I use a For Each loop to instantiate a group of controls onto my form in a row?

Tags: vb.net

I want to display a row of labels onto my form that the user defines.
An example would be the user enters that he/she wants to display 6 labels so the for each loop would go through a list of label objects and create them.

I have tried to use arrays and lists, the user would enter how many labels and it the loop would set their properties like location but I would get this error. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I already tried to search this up but the results are not what im looking for and I don't know how to instantiate multiple controls at once.

```
 Dim People As Integer
 Dim wordlength As Integer
 Dim wordChar As Integer
 Dim list As New List(Of Label)

 wordlength = CInt(InputBox("Enter your Words length"))

 Dim CharAmount(wordlength) As Label
 Dim addon As Integer = 0

    For Each item As Label In CharAmount
        list.Add(item)
    Next


    For Each item As Label In list
        With item
            .Size = New Size(30, 30)
            .Location = New Size(324 + addon, 20)
        End With
        addon += 20
        Me.Controls.Add(item)
    Next
```

The program has to display a inputed amount of labels in a row

Answer (score 0):

You need create a label before use.

```
For i = 1 to wordlength 
    Dim item As New Label() 
    list.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I don’t undestand the Dim item as New label part though. Aren’t you adding the same thing over again?

Comment: How can it be adding the same thing every time?  It's creating a `New Label` inside the loop, so each iteration will create a `New Label`.  You'd only be adding the same thing over and over if you just created one `New Label` outside the loop and then added that inside the loop.